# Rails request object contains wrong protocol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm running Rails 3.1.2 on Apache with the latest Passenger, 3.0.11. I'm using force_ssl to require a secure connection in a few of my application's actions.

The web browser is warning that although the identity of the site has been verified and the connection is encrypted, the page contains other resources which are not secure. The culprit is a reference to the Google Fonts API being made over plain http. My view contains the following:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "#{request.port}fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald"
```

I also tried this:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "http#{request.ssl? ? 's' : ''}://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald"
```

Both of these result in the stylesheet url having "http://".

I had success doing this in a Rails 3.0.5/Passenger 3.0.7/SslRequirement, but can't get it to work in Rails 3.2.1/Passenger 3.0.11/force_ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" without the http or https - that way the browser uses the same protocol as the page you are on and doesn't show any warnings.